# При подключении к сайту java.io.FileNotFoundException в android

Tags: android, kotlin

Подключаюсь к сайту https://time.is/Unix_time_now для того чтобы узнать время при выполнении `hrCon.getInputStream()` стабильный вылет с исключением `java.io.FileNotFoundException`

```
fun test() {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            try {
                var nowTime: Long = getTime()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                L.i("exception:" + e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
@Throws(Exception::class)
    private fun getTime(): Long {

        val url = "https://time.is/Unix_time_now"
        var hrCon: HttpsURLConnection = URL(url).openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
        if (hrCon.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            var istream = hrCon.getInputStream()
            val doc: Document = Jsoup.parse(istream, "UTF-8", url)
            val tags = arrayOf(
                "div[id=time_section]",
                "div[id=clock0_bg]"
            )
            var elements: Elements = doc.select(tags[0])
            for (i in tags.indices) {
                elements = elements.select(tags[i])
            }
            return elements.text().toLong()
        } else {
            return -1
        }
    }
```

Comment: Дело в самом сайте https://time.is/Unix_time_now я поставил другой и исключения не вылетело, может кто знает почему так?

Comment: Я ошибку нашел но hrCon.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK вместо != надо == теперь у меня не работает из-за того что сервер шлет 403 ошибку.

Comment: Подсуньте ему другой user-agent

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Подсунул ему: hrCon.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2")